# The transaction from (account name) to ('undefined' or account name) couldn't be successfully executed

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, testnets, ropsten

I am trying to do some testing on Ropsten testnet but I cannot deploy contract or even send Ether.

I get this error when trying to send ether:

> The transaction from "`Main account (Etherbase)`" to `'account1'` couldn't
>   be successfully executed.

Example transaction ID:

```
0xa85b767355c7bbd4ee8d97c30c100c8e04f2654e4fdebf2c93b4bfafdbe58bc7
```

It will stay at `0` confirmation and I will receive the error after about 5 mins

- Version: `0.9.2`

  - Blockchain: Ropsten testnet
- OS & Version: `windows`
- Node version: `geth 1.7.2`
- Number of blocks synchronized: `2101823`

I have seen this question asked before on here but none of the solutions help me, as I have this issue even when trying to send ether and not just contract deployment.

Comment: looks like the 'to:' key in the parameters to sendTransaction is `undefined` , you forgot to specifiy the destination address. but without code, there wouldn't be help from us

Comment: Oh I don't think that is the reason. It says that for contract deployment, but I have the same issue with sending funds from one account to another. I have updated my post to clarify this.

Comment: @cryptotrader You cannot send transactions from geth until it is fully synchronized. Right now mainnet is above 4.5M blocks.

Comment: @Ismael This is not on main net, it is on ropsten. I am able to receive eth on these account in my mist but unable to send from them. Sorry if my question wasn't clear

Comment: Does anyone have any more suggestions? Thanks

Comment: @cryptotrader It appears you have sent early another transaction https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xe9b0a8076122fcadff107124b16fefe8477608e2051d5818956013517653ee9b with a fee of 1 Gwei. Until that transaction is mined all subsequent transactions are stuck. You can replace it by sending a new transaction with the same nonce and higher fee.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be because on a low gas and gas-price. Transactions with low gas and gas-price will not be mined by miners and thus will just stuck!
**Increase both gas and gas-price.**
And note that deploying contract will need much more price than normal Eth transactions.

If this did not solve your issue please share: the Tool you are using (is it Truffle or do you try to do your transaction using Parity?) and share the values of gas and gas-price that you are using.